# Reset URL Keys for all products to "Use Default" for all store views

Tags: url-rewrite, product-urls

I've got 2 store views, recently I noticed that for some reason (either by design or by a bug) that each product has a unique `URL KEY` for both store views.

It is setup in the following way:

- Default Store
- English
- French

I need to reset all products for English and French to use the Default Store view URL key.

The store is separated by /eng and /fr so there is no reason to have a unique url key.

There are 2 ways I thought of doing this:

1. Run a MySQl Statement to delete all the keys and set back to use default:

   delete from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id = 97 and store_id != 0

But it doesn't address the fact that if more products are modified, it will continue to create new keys.

2. Another way I thought of doing this was to force the `URL Key` to be a `[GLOBAL]` attribute and not `[STORE VIEW]` But I dont know if this is possible or if this would be the best approach.

**What is the best way to set all my existing products to use the `Default` store view `URL Key` and prevent this from happening to new products?**

**Is this normal Magento behavior?**

Comment: No, this is not default behavior, the reason of this might be in the method you are using for modifying your products/creating new ones. I assume you are not doing it via admin, otherwise you wouldn't have this issue unless you want to. What method you are using for this whole process ?

Comment: I'm using an import script, it looks like this is the culprate. If you put your comments as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not default behavior, the reason of this might be in the method you are using for modifying your products/creating new ones. I assume you are not doing it via admin, otherwise you wouldn't have this issue unless you want to. It will depend upon the import method you are using.